# Downcasting a List<AbstractClass> object to what the object actually is

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `ParentClass`. Two classes are inherit from it, `FirstChildClass` and `SecondChildClass`. A class `MultipleValueTypes` contains a `Dictionary` and a method that adds values to it. My intention is to be able to pass values of different classes, which inherit from the same abstract class to the value parameter of the `Dictionary`. Therefore, I initialize the dictionary with the value `List<ParentClass>` so that I would be able to add objects made with the child classes to the Dictionary. I can do this, but I cannot access them, therefore in the abstract class I create a way to tell them apart, a virtual method that both the children classes override to return their own class type.

I test the values they return against the enum itself and based on whether the condition is fulfilled, the object would be casted as what it is instead of a `List<ParentClass>`. Is this the wrong approach? Is this impossible?

I think it should work, because in my thinking the `FirstObject` and `SecondObject` are still objects of their respective classes, so casting should work and I should be able to access the overridden method.

What doesn't work: I cannot access the method that returns what type of class it is, because it only gets methods from the `List<ParentClass>`.

What I've tried so far: searching for a way to access the method, but I did not find any.

What I still need help with: everything mentioned above.

```
public abstract class ParentClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ParentClass(string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
        }

        public enum ChildClasses
        {
            NoChildClass = 0,
            FirstChildClass = 1,
            SecondChildClass = 2
        }
        public virtual ChildClasses TypeOfClass()
        {
            return ChildClasses.NoChildClass;
        }
    }
```

```
public class FirstChildClass : ParentClass
    {
        private string _randomvalue;
        public string RandomValue { get => _randomvalue; set => _randomvalue = value; }
        public FirstChildClass(string Name) : base(Name)
        {

        }

        public void ReturnMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the FirstChildClass");
        }
        public override ChildClasses TypeOfClass()
        {
            return ChildClasses.FirstChildClass;
        }
    }
```

```
public class SecondChildClass : ParentClass
    {
        private string _randomvalue;
        public string RandomValue { get => _randomvalue; set => _randomvalue = value; }
        public SecondChildClass(string Name) : base(Name)
        {

        }
        public void ReturnMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the SecondChildClass");
        }

        public override ChildClasses TypeOfClass()
        {
            return ChildClasses.SecondChildClass;
        }
    }
```

```
class MultipleValueTypes
    {
        public Dictionary<string, List<ParentClass>> ADictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<ParentClass>>();

        public void AddObject(string Name, ParentClass variable)
        {
            if (!ADictionary.ContainsKey(Name))
            {
                ADictionary.Add(Name, new List<ParentClass>());
            }
            ADictionary[Name].Add(variable);
        }
    }
```

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FirstChildClass FirstObject = new FirstChildClass("FirstObject");
            SecondChildClass SecondObject = new SecondChildClass("SecondObject");
            MultipleValueTypes TestDictionary = new MultipleValueTypes();
            TestDictionary.AddObject("FirstObject", FirstObject);
            TestDictionary.AddObject("SecondObject", SecondObject);
            if(TestDictionary.ADictionary["FirstObject"].TypeOfClass() == ParentClass.ChildClasses.FirstChildClass) ///List<ParentClass>' does not contain a definition for 'TypeOfClass' and no accessible extension method 'TypeOfClass' accepting a first argument of type 'List<ParentClass>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
            {
                TestDictionary.ADictionary["FirstObject"] = (FirstChildClass)TestDictionary.ADictionary["FirstObject"]; ///Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dictionary.ParentClass>' to 'Dictionary.FirstChildClass
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `/// Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TextGame.Items.BaseItems>' to 'TextGame.Items.InventoryItems.Wallet'` Is a bucket that can contain many different types of items (and multiple of them) the same as as a single wallet?

Comment: @mjwills no, but that was the only way to add different types of items to a single dictionary. the wallet is initialized in ```ItemsInitializers``` and is added to the dictionary under the umbrella of the generic container. isn't downcasting theoretically valid in this scenario?

Comment: @MickyD i don't think so, that would just return what the object is at the moment which is a System.Collections.Generic.List<TextGame.Items.BaseItems>. The enum ObjectType contains the values items can possibly be, for example a WalletType is 1, then the method TypeOfObject is overridden in the Wallet class so that it returns its ObjectType. Ideally, in this scenario, it returns what it actually is, a WalletType, then this is checked against the enum and then casted to (Wallet), which is exactly what the object WalletItem is.

Comment: Ah, I saw the _"does not contain a definition for 'TypeOfObject'"_ and thought it was that. I didn't see your definition.  Taa

Comment: @MickyD yes it's a bit strange, because in my understanding a List<AbstractClass> object should be able to use the abstract class' methods and properties right? i think that's the root of the issue, and why the cast itself does not work, it does not see a BaseItems object, it sees a List object that gets BaseItems values

Comment: _"a List<AbstractClass> object should be able to use the abstract class' methods and properties right?"_ -- no, where would you get that idea? Your code example is incomplete, but from you've shown us, a `Wallet` is not a list, and the list you have, is a `List<BaseItems>`, so at best it could _contain_ a `Wallet`, and not _be_ a `Wallet`. Since it can't be a `Wallet`, obviously you can't cast it to one. Frankly, it's not at all clear what you're trying to do...

Comment: ... if you really need help, you'll need to improve your question: remove all of the domain-specific aspects, provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly the _essence_ of what you're trying to do, explain why you think it should work, explain exactly what about it doesn't work, and of course, what you've tried so far, and what you still need help with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am "new" to stack overflow so I apologize for mistakes in explaining my issue. What I am trying to do is add different objects to a dictionary's value parameter and to be able to access the objects' methods and properties. All these different objects have something in common, they're all inherited from the same abstract class. ```Wallet``` is simply an object that inherits from ```BaseItems```, which is the value of ```List<BaseItems>```. I did try to provide a minimally reproducible example, but since I am a beginner I may not have succeeded.

Comment: however I will try again to reproduce my issue in the clearest detail and I will edit the OP if I succeed. I need help understanding what I am doing wrong and what I could do better, it is not a circumstance I need to get past to achieve a goal, it is a circumstance I am learning to deal with.

Comment: Remove Name , Description , BasePrice , some field  , and constructor, that make your question be simply

Comment: @PeterDuniho edited the OP for a minimal reproducible example (a new program, independent of the contexts from before), I am not sure how to simplify it further in a way that wouldn't leave any disambiguity.

Comment: @TimChang made a new program that shows only the core issue, with all its classes.

Comment: You are trying to cast the List itself to a single object, also `TypeOfClass` is being called on the list, not an instance of the class

Comment: @SohaibJundi and there is no way this can be done? i know that TypeOfClass is being called on the list, is there no way to call it on the value of the list? that being ParentClass. if this can be done then I would cast the ParentClass itself to a single object, so it would turn from List<ParentClass> to List<FirstChildClass>

Comment: It is not clear from your update why you are storing a list as the value in your dictionary, rather than just the single object type (i.e. `ParentClass`). It is even less clear now that you've accepted the very odd answer below, because in that answer, the list can only ever retrieve the first element of the list. I mean, I'm glad you got an answer you think is useful. But, the question still remains very confusing, at least in my view.

Comment: @PeterDuniho because i wanted to add multiple objects initialized with classes which all inherit from the same abstract class.. the premise was to be able to add items to an inventory and those items to be of differing types, i will return to using a list anyway even if it works, it was good to learn about downcasting at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use indexer of the list value of the key of the dictionary here:

```
==> TestDictionary.ADictionary["FirstObject"][0]
```

Here is your code now refactored too:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var FirstObject = new FirstChildClass("FirstObject");
    var SecondObject = new SecondChildClass("SecondObject");
    FirstObject.ReturnMessage();
    SecondObject.ReturnMessage();
    MultipleValueTypes TestDictionary = new MultipleValueTypes();
    TestDictionary.AddObject("FirstObject", FirstObject);
    TestDictionary.AddObject("SecondObject", SecondObject);
    if ( TestDictionary.ADictionary["FirstObject"][0].TypeOfClass()
         == ParentClass.ChildClasses.FirstChildClass )
    {
      TestDictionary.ADictionary["FirstObject"][0]
        = (FirstChildClass)TestDictionary.ADictionary["FirstObject"][0];
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}

public abstract class ParentClass
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string RandomValue { get; set; }
  public ParentClass(string Name)
  {
    this.Name = Name;
  }
  public virtual void ReturnMessage()
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"This is the {this.GetType().Name} instance");
  }
  public virtual ChildClasses TypeOfClass()
  {
    return ChildClasses.NoChildClass;
  }
  public enum ChildClasses
  {
    NoChildClass = 0,
    FirstChildClass = 1,
    SecondChildClass = 2
  }
}

public class FirstChildClass : ParentClass
{
  public FirstChildClass(string Name)
    : base(Name)
  {

  }
  public override ChildClasses TypeOfClass()
  {
    return ChildClasses.FirstChildClass;
  }
}

public class SecondChildClass : ParentClass
{
  public SecondChildClass(string Name)
    : base(Name)
  {
  }
  public override ChildClasses TypeOfClass()
  {
    return ChildClasses.SecondChildClass;
  }
}

class MultipleValueTypes
{
  public readonly Dictionary<string, List<ParentClass>> ADictionary
    = new Dictionary<string, List<ParentClass>>();
  public void AddObject(string Name, ParentClass variable)
  {
    if ( !ADictionary.ContainsKey(Name) )
    {
      ADictionary.Add(Name, new List<ParentClass>());
    }
    ADictionary[Name].Add(variable);
  }
}
```

Comment: damn this is what I was looking for, I did not forget it, I did not even know that I need to use that index and I was trying to find how to actually access the elements of the list because obviously it's not ok to manipulate the list object itself directly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to cast the whole list from `List<ParentClass>` to `List<FirstChildClass>` and `List<SecondChildClass>`, then Linq is your friend, just use the `Cast` function:

```
List<FirstChildClass> firstChildClasses = TestDictionary.ADictionary["FirstObject"]
    .Cast<FirstChildClass>().ToList();
List<SecondChildClass> secondChildClasses = TestDictionary.ADictionary["SecondObject"]
   .Cast<SecondChildClass>().ToList();
```